# Create view from another Database on the same server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Is it possible to create a view that takes the same form as another view in a different database? Something like:

```
USE MyDB
CREATE VIEW MyView
AS
     AnotherDB.MyView
```

I want the new view to access data on the database where I'm creating the view. Just selecting * from the original view would take data from the other one and it would also create an unwanted dependency.

Comment: No, this is not possible.

Comment: USE MyDB
CREATE VIEW OtherDB.dbo.MyView
AS
begin
--Your Script Here
end